# Microsoft Teams login problems after moving client to different computer

Tags: windows, windows-11, office365, microsoft-teams

I have a client that is having login problems with her Microsoft apps after moving her to a newer computer.  It is mainly problems with Teams.  It will give errors such as "cant connect to network"  when in fact she is connected to the network and will also give error code "0xcaa80000".  I have performed a network reset, which has seemed to fix the "cant connect to network" error (so far).  But we still get the 0xCAA80000 error almost every morning when she starts her computer.  I can sign in just on teams just fine on her profile, though.  It almost seems to be a profile specific problem, but I'm not 100% sure.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try the methods [here](https://windowsreport.com/0xcaa80000/) and report back. You could also try another user account on the same computer.